# Extract value based on coordinates in another data frame

Tags: r, extract, coordinates

I have two data frames. One (df1) has expected values and the other (df2) has observed values. Each value in the dfs have corresponding coordinates. How can I extract the value of df1 at the coordinates in df2? I.e. find the expected from df1 at the coordinates in df2 to compare the expected versus observed values?

My dfs look like this

df1

| Lat | Long | var1.predicted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 0.8 |
| 1 | 4 | 0.7 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 4 | 0.9 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.6 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.4 |

df2

| Lat | Long | observed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |

I don't know where to begin. I want to extract the var1.predicted value from df1 for the same Lat/Long combinations found in df2.

I tried

```
df2$Expected <- df1[as.matrix(df2)]
```

but it's giving me an error since df1 has more rows than df2.

Comment: One way: `merge(df1, df2, by=c("Lat","Long"))`

Comment: `merge(df1, df2)`?

Comment: I don't want to merge the dfs. I just need the values from one column in df1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do a `left_join`:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df2, df1, by = c("Lat", "Long")) %>%
  select(Lat, Long, Expected = var1.predicted, observed)
```

OR
base R:

```
df2$Expected <- df1$var1.predicted[match(paste(df2$Lat, df2$Long), paste(df1$Lat, df1$Long))]
```

```
  Lat Long Expected observed
1   1    3      0.8        0
2   2    4      0.9        1
```

Comment: Is there a way to add some variance in the filtering? The coordinates of my expected values weren't generated with the exact coordinates as my observed values, so they give me NAs when extracting them because they don't have the exact values. Is there a way to add a range of +/- 0.01 to the to try to capture that variation?